# I made a simple calculator kivy program in Python. But an arror is showing up and i don't understand what it's trying to say

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, calculator

This is the code -

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput



class mygl(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(mygl, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "input calculation :", font_size = 40))
        self.calc = TextInput(Multiline = False)
        self.add_widget(self.calc)
        self.sub = Button(text = "Submit")
        self.add_widget(self.sub)
        self.sub.bind(in_press = self.press())

    def press(self, instance):
        a = self.calc.text
        b = a.split(" ")
        if b[1] == "+":
            self.add_widget(Label(text = b[0] + b[2]))
        elif b[1] == "-":
            self.add_widget(Label(text = b[0] - b[2]))
        elif b[1] == "X":
            self.add_widget(Label(text = b[0] * b[2]))


class calculator(App):
    def build(self):
        return mygl()

calculator().run()
```

this is the error -

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\OneDrive\Desktop\Aditya Coding VS code\no.py", line 37, in 
calculator().run()
File "C:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
self._run_prepare()
File "C:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
root = self.build()
File "c:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\OneDrive\Desktop\Aditya Coding VS code\no.py", line 35, in build
return mygl()
File "c:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\OneDrive\Desktop\Aditya Coding VS code\no.py", line 16, in **init**
self.calc = TextInput(Multiline = False)
File "C:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\textinput.py", line 528, in **init**
super(TextInput, self).**init**(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\focus.py", line 367, in **init**
super(FocusBehavior, self).**init**(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in **init**
super(Widget, self).**init**(**kwargs)
File "kivy_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.**init**
TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
PS C:\Users\Vinay Mohnot\OneDrive\Desktop\Aditya Coding VS code>

I am a beginner so I don't why this is showing up

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the line:

```
self.calc = TextInput(Multiline = False)
```

the keyword should be `multiline` (no capitals):

```
self.calc = TextInput(multiline = False)
```

Also,

```
self.sub.bind(in_press = self.press())
```

should be:

```
self.sub.bind(in_press = self.press)
```

without `()`.